# Custom position for each cell in CollectionView

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I'm currently using an `UICollectionView` with custom xib to recreate that 
[mockup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/azxaR.png)

With `sizeForItemAtIndexPath` delegate method I'm able to change size of each `UICollectionViewCell`:

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGSize {
    let screenSize = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds
    let screenWidth = screenSize.width
    let screenHeight = screenSize.height
    let customHeight = screenHeight / 7

    if indexPath.row == 2{
        return CGSizeMake(screenWidth / 3, customHeight * 2);
    }
    if indexPath.row == 6{
        return CGSizeMake(screenWidth, customHeight * 2);
    }

    return CGSizeMake(screenWidth / 3, customHeight);
}
```

And that is what I get :

[image]

So I am not able to change the y of the first two images to the top and add tow more image at the bottom (like in the mockup).

Comment: use custom flow layout..

Comment: check this tutorial https://www.raywenderlich.com/107439/uicollectionview-custom-layout-tutorial-pinterest

Comment: https://github.com/bryceredd/RFQuiltLayout